# How to reduce memory consumption in android

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

I am new in android field. I don't known the how to reduce the memory consumption in android. In my application large number of  image is drawn from the web and display into grid view. When running the application "out memory problem is occur".

Please help me

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, some code would actually be helpful..

Answer (score 3):

**1)** scale down and reduce the size of images

```
/**
 * decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
 * 
 * @param file
 * @param requiredSize
 * @return
 */
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File file, int requiredSize) {
    try {

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize
                    || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file),
                null, o2);

        return bmp;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } finally {
    }
    return null;
}
```

**2)** use `bitmap.Recycle();`

**3)** use `System.gc();` for indicating to the VM that it would be a good time to run the garbage collector

Comment: Also, spot your memory allocations with DDMS. Don't recreate new variables all the time. But resizing Bitmap will probably do the trick !